# Possible to upgrade redmine 1.3.2 stable (MySQL) installed from repository?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04, upgrade, redmine, redmine-plugins

Some month ago I installed Redmine from repository using apt-get install redmine. I didn't know much about redmine so I just followed a guide, created a MySql DB and a user and installed it. Version is 1.3.2

Later on I wanted to install some plugins and see that most of them require redmine 1.4.x

So I thought about upgrading, but this is the latest repository file. Is there a "safe" way to upgrade redmine to a newer version?

Server is running Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: I don't want to upgrade ubuntu since there are a lot of needed applications running on it. Will there never be a newer version of redmine for 12.04 ?

Comment: why not to clone code from [github](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/), switch to needed branch (`1.4-stable`), setup environment and start server (I believe official site has appropriate instruction how to do it). PS I suggest to use last Redmine version - `2.4-stable`